# how to run a foreach loop on array of arrays to calc and number of few property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

for example YieldCalcValues could be equal to somethins like that => [ [ 850, 500 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 1200, 5000 ], [ 526170, 526170 ] ]

i want to make a foreach loop that calculate the yieldper for each product.

how could i done it right?

````
let AllRealestateTotalWorthItems = response.products?.find((x:any) => x.code === 'realestate')?.items?.map((({
  worth
}) => worth));

let AllRealestateAnnualExpenses = response.products?.find((x:any) => x.code === 'realestate')?.items?.map((({
    annualExpenses
  }) => annualExpenses));

  let AllRealestateAppreciation= response.products?.find((x:any) => x.code === 'realestate')?.items?.map((({
    appreciation
  }) => appreciation));

  let AllRealestateExpectedRevenue = response.products?.find((x:any) => x.code === 'realestate')?.items?.map((({
    expectedRevenue
  }) => expectedRevenue));

  const YieldCalcValues = [AllRealestateAnnualExpenses,AllRealestateAppreciation,AllRealestateExpectedRevenue,AllRealestateTotalWorthItems];

  console.log(YieldCalcValues);

  YieldCalcValues.forEach((a:any) =>{
   let yieldPer = 0;

   yieldPer = ((a.AllRealestateExpectedRevenue - a.AllRealestateAnnualExpenses)/(a.AllRealestateTotalWorthItems) + (a.AllRealestateAppreciation / 100));
   
   console.log(yieldPer)
  }) ```
````

Comment: please add the wanted result and how you calculate it.

Comment: its in the yieldPer  in the forEach loop

Comment: ((expectedRevenue- annualExpenses)/(worth) + (appreciation/ 100));

Comment: and the result of all?

Comment: Following your array, could you say to us what is expectedRevenue, annualExpenses, worth and appreciation?

Comment: [ [ 850, 500 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 1200, 5000 ], [ 526170, 526170 ] ]   => [AllRealestateAnnualExpenses,AllRealestateAppreciation,AllRealestateExpectedRevenue,AllRealestateTotalWorthItems]

Comment: its like the one above

Comment: For example, [ 850, 500 ]  850 is expectedRevenue? 500 is annualExpenses?

Comment: no, 850 is annualExpenses, 3 is Appreciation , 1200 expectedRevenue, 526170 worth

Comment: @OMRIDAN, please add this information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you could try something like this:

```js
let input = [ [ 850, 500 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 1200, 5000 ], [ 526170, 526170 ] ]

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length/4; i ++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < input.length/2; j ++) {
       let AllRealestateAnnualExpenses = input[i][j];
       let AllRealestateAppreciation = input[i + 1][j];
       let AllRealestateExpectedRevenue = input[i + 2][j];
       let AllRealestateTotalWorthItems = input [i + 3][j];
       
       let yieldPer = ((AllRealestateExpectedRevenue - AllRealestateAnnualExpenses)/(AllRealestateTotalWorthItems) + (AllRealestateAppreciation / 100));
       console.log(yieldPer);
      }  
    }
```

Using your suggestion on comment, I made a simple for loop to caluclate `yieldPer`

Comment: @OMRIDAN I updated my previous answer. This one could be correct?